# Use google script to put 2 columns into a single multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to take 2 columns in a google spreadsheet and merge them into a single array in hopes that I can take these 2 columns and use `setValues` on a new sheet.

### Why?

I'm eventually taking 2 different sheets and basically doing a large scale vlookup and transferring all results and desired columns into a single, new sheet. I can get the full `dataRange`, loop through each array, grabbing the values I want and pushing them to a new array. But is there an easier way? If I can look through just row1 and get the headers and their index, can I just put all of column A and column D in a multi-dimensional array?

### Example

> Header1 | H2 | H3

I want H1 and H3 and their rows so I can put them in a new sheet as such

Multi-Dimensional Array:

> [ [H1, H3], [dataH1,dataH3] ]

### Current Code

```
  var freqArr = new Array(); //Array with sheet data
  var myArray = new Array(); //Blank array to house header index
  var freqSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('KEY_test_test');
  var freqData = freqSheet.getDataRange(); //all data
  var freqNumRows = freqData.getNumRows(); //number of rows
  var freqNumCol = freqData.getNumColumns(); //number of columns
  freqArr = freqSheet.getRange(1, 1, freqNumRows, freqNumCol).getValues();
  for (i = 0;i<1;++i){
    for (j = 0;j<freqNumCol;++j){
      if (freqArr[i][j].toString() == 'Header1' || freqArr[i][j].toString() == 'Header3'){
      myArray.push([j]);
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(myArray);
```

### Where I'm Stuck

What I'm doing right now is looping through the first row to get the header indexes I want (should look like this `[ 0, 2 ]`) but all that is returning in my log is []. I plan to use this array of indexes to loop through my `freqData` and grab the indexes of each nested array.

Any advice would be great. I'm just starting to learn google script and I'm teaching myself. Thanks

### UPDATE TO CODE:

It turns out that `.toString() == 'Header1'` will not return a match but after more google fu, I found `.toString().match('Header1') == 'Header1'` will return what I need. See below for update

```
  var freqArr = new Array(); //Array with sheet data
  var myArray = new Array(); //Blank array to house header index
  var freqSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('KEY_test_test');
  var freqData = freqSheet.getDataRange(); //all data
  var freqNumRows = freqData.getNumRows(); //number of rows
  var freqNumCol = freqData.getNumColumns(); //number of columns
  freqArr = freqSheet.getRange(1, 1, freqNumRows, freqNumCol).getValues();
  for (i = 0;i<1;++i){
    for (j = 0;j<freqNumCol;++j){
      if (freqArr[i][j].toString().match('Header1') == 'Header1' || freqArr[i][j].toString().match('Header3') == 'Header3'){
      myArray.push(j);
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(myArray);
```

will return `[ 0.0 , 2.0 ]`.

But still, my question remains, is there a faster way to get 2(n) columns that are not side-by-side and put them into an array so that you can use `.setValues`?

Answer (score 7):

## Answer

> But still, my question remains, is there a faster way to get 2(n) columns that are not side-by-side and put them into an array so that you can use .setValues?

Yes, there are many ways. One of them is the use of a JavaScript method: [array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

### Code

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var array = [];
  data.forEach(function(row){
      array.push([row[0],row[5]]);
    });
  sheet.getRange(1,10,array.length,2).setValues(array);
}
```

## Explanation

Get the active sheet

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

Get the all the values on  `sheet`

```
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

Initialize a variable to hold the array

```
  var array = [];
```

Get the values of the first and sixth columns (A and F) (zero based index)

```
  data.forEach(function(row){
      array.push([row[0],row[5]]);
    });
```

Return the values to a range starting on J1 and ending on column K and the required row (one based index)

```
  sheet.getRange(1,10,array.length,2).setValues(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `getRowsData()` function on the [Simple Mail Merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge#section4) tutorial.  It will get all the data in a sheet and return it as objects.  You could then access the data as `myData[i].header1`  It will remove spaces and "normalize" the header.  So a header such as *My Header name* will be `myData[i].myHEaderName`

You could limit the returned data to only the columns you need if you wish.